# Can't get Autokey to reassign ctrl+c to ctrl+j while using Dvorak

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dvorak, autokey

I'm in the process of switching to the Dvorak keyboard layout, and I'd like to reassign the common shortcuts so they remain where they were. It seems that Autokey has worked for a lot of people, but I haven't had any luck. I have tested the sample scripts that come with Autokey and they work just fine, so it's definitely a problem with my script.

Here's what I've done: created a top level folder, created a script underneath it, typed:

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+c")
```

Assigned ctrl+j as the hotkey:

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK9Qm.png)

then switched to the Dvorak keyboard layout and tried copying. Autokey ignores Dvorak - ctrl+j does work, but it's the QWERTY J, not the Dvorak J.

Any ideas/suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! In the keyboard layout handler I had QWERTY first in the list of keyboard layouts. When I put Dvorak first, Autokey worked properly.

[screenshot of the keyboard layout handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsOyv.png)